# How to debug MSSQL driver issues from Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, django, ubuntu, networking, odbc-sql-server-driver

Similar to another couple of questions I've seen, I'm in the dark place of having no choice other than to connect to MSSQL from Django.

I'm intermittently (but around 50% of the time, the rest it works fine) getting the error;

> django.db.utils.Error: ('[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x274c (10060) (SQLGetData)')

Note, I also get this one sometimes;

> django.db.utils.Error: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x68 (104) (SQLGetData)')

I think it's network related, I've previously tried swapping out `pyodbc` versions, swapping between `FreeTDS` and Microsoft driver for unix, and trying `pyodbc` and `pyodbc-azure`.

The machines in question are Vagrant boxes on a private network with fixed IPs (Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 8), SQL Server is SQL Server Express 2016.

I can't even work out how to find a more detailed log on the Windows side to work out why/how it keeps dropping/closing the connection. Note - I've looked in the SQL Server and Windows event logs and they don't seem to be picking anything up.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful links based on the error codes logged:

[10060](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326282.aspx)

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.
>   When connecting to SQL Server, this failure may be caused by the fact
>   that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote
>   connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)

Generally, you can fix this by navigating to the SQL Server instance and making sure remote connections are allowed. There is a configuration setting in SSMS for this. You also want to make sure the server is set up to use integrated mode security. i.e - windows/ad credentials and sql server credentials. You can define a SQL server user not bound to a user windows identity.

Comment: Your link has a trailing single quote; it should be https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326282.aspx .